# getting line number of selected item in tkinter.ListBox

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox

I am creating a simple listbox. While assigning values, I put custom index numbers 1, 5, 6. but when I try to get index of list it return automatic index number i.e. 0, 1, 2 rather than 1, 5, 6. i don't know how to get custom id? Below is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.geometry("300x300")

w = Label(root, text='GeeksForGeeks', font="50")
w.pack()

my_list = Listbox(root)
my_list.insert(1, 'hamid')
my_list.insert(5, 'Sami')
my_list.insert(6, 'Hassan')
my_list.pack()


def get_list_id():
    print(my_list.curselection())


my_button = Button(root, text='click', command=get_list_id)
my_button.pack()
mainloop()
```

Comment: Basically you cannot get what you want.

Comment: @acw1668 then what is the best solution if I want to save an id in database for corresponding text.

Comment: You can use a dictionary like `{'hamid':1, 'Sami':5, 'Hassan':6}` as long as the keys are unique, then you can use the selected item to get the ID. Or you can combine the ID and the string into one string like '1: hamid', then you can extract the ID from the selected item. Think more and you can find more solutions.